# Is it bad practice to add non standard attributes to DOM elements? - HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it considered bad practice to use non-standard HTML attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117933/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-non-standard-html-attributes)

Hi folks,

I'm building a javascript library, the idea of which is to add functionality to various elements on page.

Easiest way for complete isolation would be to add a non standard attribute

e.g. `<div special="true" >...</div>`

Other alternatives are classes and onclick javascript.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: "Other alternatives are classes and onclick javascript." => or jQuery's `data()` method.

Comment: Opposite to other responders, I see nothing wrong with using custom attributes on your site - I use them for different purposes in may places, and had no issues with browser incompatibility when using those attributes together with javascript. An alternative could be to use css classes as markers, but I think it's not as clean.

Comment: @Audrey Please add this as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML5 supports ["data"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) type attributes, but in general for a modern day site, this would cause most sites to fail validation if they are going for any doctype other than HTML5.

So that would just be adding a barrier to entry for potential users of your library.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it.  I've learned the hard way that this is not cross-browser.  I had a jQuery-intensive app totally fail to function in Chrome because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to advise whether adopting this kind of approach is the best way or not. However, it's worth pointing out that there are other libraries out there that are successfully using the HTML5 data- attributes [referred to by jondavidjon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909527/is-it-bad-practice-to-add-non-standard-attributes-to-dom-elements-html-javascr/4909536#4909536). For an example of this, check out [KnockoutJS](http://www.knockoutjs.com) - fully cross-browser compatible (including IE6).